# When Double-Clicking On Associated File, File Won't Open And Program Crashes

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click, file-association

I'm having a peculiar problem with opening a file in its associated program. First I double-click on a file, click "Open with...", then I click my way to the Debug folder in my program's project file and run the executable. This is to simulate opening a file in the program associated with it as if the program were actually installed on my computer.

Here's the entire code from Program.cs:

```
namespace TriviaAuthor_v10
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
            if (args.Length > 0)
                Application.Run(new frmMain(args[0]));
            else
                Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the code for the two constructors for the main form:

```
    public frmMain(string autoopenfilepath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        filepath = autoopenfilepath;
        OpenTheFile(filepath);
    }

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And here's the code for opening the file:

```
    private void OpenTheFile(string ThisFilePath)
    {
        // First we get the filename.
        filename = Path.GetFileName(ThisFilePath);
        FilenameSansExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ThisFilePath);
        // Create a file stream.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(ThisFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        // Create the writer for data.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        GameInfo.GameTitle = br.ReadString();
        GameInfo.GameAuthor = br.ReadString();
        GameInfo.DateCreated = br.ReadString();
        GameInfo.NumberOfQuestions = br.ReadInt32();
        GameInfo.TitlePageImagePresent = br.ReadBoolean();
        GameInfo.TitlePageImage = br.ReadString();
        GameInfo.IntroScreenAudioPresent = br.ReadBoolean();
        GameInfo.IntroScreenAudio = br.ReadString();
        GameInfo.FinalScoreAudioPresent = br.ReadBoolean();
        GameInfo.FinalScoreAudio = br.ReadString();
        GameInfo.ActiveQuestion = br.ReadInt32();

        if (GameInfo.NumberOfQuestions > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameInfo.NumberOfQuestions; i++)
            {
                clsQuestionClass Question = new clsQuestionClass();

                Question.NewQuestion = br.ReadString();
                Question.Points = br.ReadInt32();
                Question.QuestionType = br.ReadInt32();
                Question.QuestionImagePresent = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.QuestionImage = br.ReadString();

                Question.QuestionAudioPresent = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.QuestionAudio = br.ReadString();

                Question.IncludeTimer = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.TimerTime = br.ReadInt32();
                Question.TickTock = br.ReadBoolean();

                Question.AIsChecked = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.AnswerA = br.ReadString();
                Question.AIsCorrect = br.ReadBoolean();

                Question.BIsChecked = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.AnswerB = br.ReadString();
                Question.BIsCorrect = br.ReadBoolean();

                Question.CIsChecked = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.AnswerC = br.ReadString();
                Question.CIsCorrect = br.ReadBoolean();

                Question.DIsChecked = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.AnswerD = br.ReadString();
                Question.DIsCorrect = br.ReadBoolean();

                Question.TrueOrFalse = br.ReadBoolean();

                Question.FillInBlankAnswer = br.ReadString();

                Question.AnswerResponseImagePresent = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.AnswerResponseImage = br.ReadString(); ;
                Question.CorrectAnswerResponse = br.ReadString();
                Question.IncorrectAnswerResponse = br.ReadString();

                Question.CorrectAnswerResponseAudioPresent = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.CorrectAnswerResponseAudio = br.ReadString();
                Question.IncorrectAnswerResponseAudioPresent = br.ReadBoolean();
                Question.IncorrectAnswerResponseAudio = br.ReadString();

                Questions.Add(Question);
                Questions.Count();
            }
        }
        fs.Close();
        br.Close();
        QuestionIndex = GameInfo.ActiveQuestion;
        LoadGameIntoGameGUI(Questions[QuestionIndex]);
        this.Text = "Trivia Author v1.0 - " + FilenameSansExtension;
        ProjectNeedsSaving = false;
        saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = closeprojecttoolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = exportgametoolStripMenuItem.Enabled =
        printToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = printPreviewToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = tsbtnProjectClose.Visible =
        ProjectIsOpen = saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = tsbtnSaveProject.Enabled = btnShowProjectReview.Enabled = true;

        UpdateGameSummary();
    }
```

Note: "OpenTheFile(string ThisFilePath)" is used for both opening the file using an OpenFileDialog and when I try to open a file by double-clicking on it.

So here's the problem: when I run the program in Visual Studio 2013 and then open the file (using OpenFileDialog) the file opens with no problems. But when I try to open the file by double-clicking it and opening it with the executable in the program's Debug folder, I see the program's splash screen and then the program aborts. It

looks to me like the file's path is being relayed to "OpenTheFile()" correctly. And because the program is running outside Visual Studio, I get no error messages, not even from the operating system.

Comment: What does the `AutoOpenFile` method do?

Comment: what happens when you step thru the code.. do you see anything that stands out immediately that would draw attention to the potential problem..? have you tried adding `FileShare.Read` to this line 
`FileStream fs = new FileStream(ThisFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`

Comment: You can use `try` `catch` with `AutoOpenFile(filepath);` and get the info about the exception (into a file or message box).

Comment: Sorry about that, Guffa. I've updated it so that "AutoOpenFile()" is now "OpenTheFile()."

Comment: Sorry about that, Guffa. I've updated it so that "AutoOpenFile()" is now "OpenTheFile()." MethodMan: Adding FileShare.Read didn't help. Nadia: I tried try-catch, but it looks like the program crashes before the MessageBox has a chance to display.

Comment: Use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(), now you can debug it.  You ought to pay some attention to dealing with unhandled exceptions, write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log or display e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Comment: If your running the debug version of the program what does it say in the details popup about what happened? Are you opening it with any command line args?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start again. You check arguments at the very beginning of your application. If it reaches `LoadGameIntoGameGUI()` and crushes there (after reading a file), it means that something is passed to the program. As you mention that you've added a message box, I assume that now you run the right version of the program, but you still have an exception. Is it exactly the same exception? If so, would you mind posting your code for `LoadGameIntoGameGUI`?

Btw, `if` here is unnecessary, if `GameInfo.NumberOfQuestions==0` the loop will be ignored anyway:

```
 if (GameInfo.NumberOfQuestions > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GameInfo.NumberOfQuestions; i++)
```

What are these numbers and questions? You pass one of them into `LoadGameIntoGameGUI`, are you sure it's correct? You can add log-file and inspect the input. Something like `File.WriteAllText("your log.txt", question.ToString());` (make sure `ToString` returns something meaningful).

Comment: Thanks, Nadia, but the MessageBox neer gets a chance to show. I also tried the example at this link: http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions but it didn't work either. Is there a way to log the unhandled exception and store it somewhere? Also, the code in Program.cs is identical to an earlier version of this project and double-clicked files open just fine in that one, so I'm wondering if the string containing the filepath (from args[0] in Program.cs) isn't making it to its destination in the main program file (OpenTheFile() in frmMain.cs).

Comment: It seems like the exception is generated by the OS, not your application. I'd tried to write a log after executing each line of code, maybe this can clarify something. Also you can comment out some parts of your code, starting with those you regard as suspicious, so you'll see if you're right about them or not.

Comment: Another thing - have you looked and Windows Event Log? There can be something about it.

Comment: Nadia: I posted something about the Windows Event Log above. It was too long to post here as a comment.

Comment: Nadia: After right-clicking on a file, I navigate to "C:\Users\Reuben\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Visual C# 2013 Projects\Trivia Author v101 With FindActiveQuestion\BYOTG v10\bin\Debug\TriviaAuthor_v10.exe". In the Event Log, it says "C:\Users\Reuben\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Visual C# 2013 Projects\Trivia Author v101 With AutoOpen2\BYOTG v10\bin\Debug\TriviaAuthor_v10.exe". This is the wrong folder, obviously. Anything I can do to make sure the folder I navigate to is the one I end up with?

Comment: Hmm... rename or delete the wrong file. Also, changing the version of the application in VS may help.

Comment: Nadia: I tried renaming and deleting the wrong file, but the problem persists. Also, I managed to capture the args.Length in Program.cs by passing it to frmSpashScreen and displaying it there in a MessageBox. args.Length comes up as 0. Since this value originated in Program.cs, it looks like the file path isn't being passed to Program.cs when I double-click on an associated file.